# Procedure with looping and execute immediate

Tags: oracle, pls-00103

Recently I have started preparing datamarts for regular reporting process, and tried to make some use of procedures with parameters.

So I read [this guideline](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/162/how-to-create-a-sql-server-stored-procedure-with-parameters/) and tried to replicate but confused with  error in compiling.

Here is my code:

```
create or replace procedure mig_rate @rep_date date AS 
    create or replace table mig_temp1(
    report_date date,
    portfolio string,
    bucket integer,
    Q integer);
begin    
    for j in 1..7 loop 
        for t in 0..32 loop
       -- execute immediate 'bla-bla-bla insert statement mig_temp1
        end loop;
    end loop;
end
```

This results in `PLS-00103` saying that `@` symbol was unexpected.

What's wrong with the syntax, how should I put the parameters into the procedure??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thing wrong is that you're trying to use SQL Server syntax in an Oracle database.

Firstly, Oracle [object names have to start with a letter](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/sql_elements008.htm) (unless you use quoted identifiers, but please don't) and... well, here are the relevant parts:

> Nonquoted identifiers must begin with an alphabetic character from
>   your database character set. Quoted identifiers can begin with any
>   character.
>
> Nonquoted identifiers can contain only alphanumeric characters from
>   your database character set and the underscore (_), dollar sign ($),
>   and pound sign (#). Database links can also contain periods (.) and
>   "at" signs (@). Oracle strongly discourages you from using $ and # in
>   nonquoted identifiers.
>
> Quoted identifiers can contain any characters and punctuations marks
>   as well as spaces. However, neither quoted nor nonquoted identifiers
>   can contain double quotation marks or the null character (\0).

... so you can't use `@` at all in the procedure name, and don't need to as that's a SQL Server thing (I think, I don't use that!).

**Edit**: see, I'm so unfamiliar with SQL Server I misread what it was doing. Your procedure name is OK, but that's not how you declare parameters; it should start:

```
create or replace procedure mig_rate(rep_date date) as
...
```

Secondly, you can't create (declare?) a table like that in an Oracle procedure. It looks like you want a temporary table for the duration of the procedure, but that's not how Oracle works; you can create a global temporary table outside the procedure but it's a permanent database object - only the data is temporary.

You can use a [PL/SQL collection](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e17126/composites.htm#CHDBHJEI) instead but it depends what you want to do with it. If it's a staging area before inserting into a normal table then you might be able to do it as a single SQL command, which would perform better.

I'm not sure why you'd want to use dynamic SQL (`execute immediate`) here...

Please refer to the [PL/SQL language reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e17126/overview.htm) and Oracle-specific sites rather than SQL Server-specific sites to learn what to do; there are very significant differences in how they work.

Comment: Alex! Great thanks for the answer, I've been away for a while.I am going to study  your links, and then probably i'll come up with some new questions!)
The reason I want to use execute mmediate is that the tables I reference have column names  like x_1, x_2, x_3 ... So I want to loop through them in the "for t in 0..32 loop"